# GCP Static IP is not attaching itself to Kubernetes ingress

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, kubernetes-ingress

I've created an ingress and have attached a metadata annotation of:

```
kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: staging-abcrad-api-static-ip
```

However even though this IP address exists*, it does not get attached - and it's been an hour or longer already.

How can I diagnose this? What may be the issue?

*

```
gcloud compute addresses list
NAME                          REGION       ADDRESS          STATUS
staging-abcrad-api-static-ip               *****retracted   RESERVED
staging-abcsub-static-ip                  *****retracted   RESERVED
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the ingress controller logs: https://serverfault.com/questions/862308/how-do-i-view-logs-for-my-kubernetes-ingress-controller?rq=1

In my case I overlooked the fact I had:

```
kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
```